# Accessing Cookies From Webbrowser Control

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile, webbrowser-control, smartphone

I have a Windows mobile 6 application that contains a Webbrowser control to navigate some intranet sites.
Is it possible to somehow access the know cookies that are being set by pages as they are displayed in browser control?

Since the compact frame work haw no ObjectScripting method I cant figure any work around that could do this.

Many thanks for your help

Tony

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way of doing this.
The only possibility might be undocumented functions in the underlying activeX control.  This wouldn't be possible in managed code though.